# "which" command gives me the source code and not the path of a command

Tags: shell, virtualenv

I'm working with some python virtualenvs, and I was wondering how the workon command was made.

So I made a `which workon` to get the path of workon.
I had directly the **whole source code** of workon --- so I got an answer to my question --- but I expected a path.

What does it mean? Isn't workon contained in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`workon` is a shell function (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/92a411652e38e351ae44a8c85f2c164093fa3eb3/virtualenvwrapper.sh?at=master#cl-687)), not a separate script.

I'm not sure if every shell will show you the function source when you run `which`, but at least the zsh does.

Comment: So when I installed my virtualenv tools, I modified my shell in some way?

Comment: @vmonteco some functions got registered (just like aliases can be registered). If you don't load the virtualenv tools, the functions won't be registered.

Comment: It didn't make sense for me but I just remembered I had to add a `source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` (The file your link points to) to my **~/.zshrc**. Here is the explanation! :) Furthermore I didn't add this line to my **~/.bashrc** and **workon** didn't work anymore when I launched **bash**.